# Yii2 Theme integration image not found

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I created a new application using **Yii2** and added a new theme:

Created a directory in `/var/www/html/<project_name>/web/themes/<theme_name>`

Then created sub-directory and associated files.

```
<theme_name>
    -layouts
        main.php
    -css
        style.css
    -js
        scrippt.js
    -images
        logo.jpg
```

After that registered my theme in `config/web.php`

```
$config = [
    ..........
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/<theme_name>'],
                //'baseUrl'   => '@theme/<theme_name>/'
          ]
        ],
    ...........
    ]
];
```

Then I changed `assets/AppAsset.php`

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@app/themes/<theme_name>';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/scrippt.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [

    ];
}
```

In main.php:

```
  <img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="">
```

**Error :** logo.jpg not found.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

After you call `$bundle = YourAssetBundle::register($this);` in view, you can use `$bundle->baseUrl` and prefix it to the image path in the image tag.

```
<?= Html::img($bundle->baseUrl.'/images/logo.jpg')?>
```

and I guess`/var/www/html/<project_name>/web/themes/<theme_name>` should be changed to `/var/www/html/<project_name>/themes/<theme_name>` because there is `@app` alias in your AssetBundle everywhere (not @web).

Comment: @Supravat This is what you are looking for. Also follow his advice regarding the moving of the theme folder, in web you should not have any other php files besides index.php as a security measure.

Comment: In my layout , I register assets as `<?php $bundle = AppAsset::register($this);; ?>` then use it of following `<?= Html::img($bundle->baseUrl.'/images/logo.png')?>`, lot of thanx for your answer.